# searching string on two text files using python

Tags: python, string, search

Using python, How can I process two text files.
for example: a.txt has 5 groups and b.txt also have 4 groups.
b.txt will look for group available on a.txt. If found, write it to output.txt and if not found, do not write it on output.txt.
numbers in the group should be matching but order it is not important.

a.txt

```
GROUP :[11111, 22222, 33333]
GROUP :[22222, 11111]
GROUP :[46098]
GROUP :[66666, 55555, 44444]
GROUP :[55555, 44444]
```

b.txt

```
GROUP :[11111, 33333]
GROUP :[46098]
GROUP :[22222, 11111]
GROUP :[44444, 55555, 66666]
```

output.txt

```
GROUP :[22222, 11111]
GROUP :[46098]
GROUP :[44444, 55555, 66666]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest thing in the world, but should get the job done:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('a.txt', 'r') as a:
    a_list = []
    for line in a:
        groups = line.split(':')[1]
        groups = groups.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
        groups = groups.split(', ')
        a_list.append(groups)

with open('b.txt', 'r') as b:
    b_list = []
    for line in b:
        groups = line.split(':')[1]
        groups = groups.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
        groups = groups.split(', ')
        b_list.append(groups)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    a_counter = [Counter(i) for i in a_list]
    for group in b_list:
        if Counter(group) in a_counter:
            output.write(f"GROUP :{group}\n")
```

Comment: thank you very much, can you please explain your code? if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

With regex and re module :

```
import re

grp_tmpl = list()

# Register all groups
f = open('b.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    grp_tmpl.append(sorted(re.findall('\d+', line)))

# Find groups
out = open('output.txt', 'w')
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    for t in grp_tmpl:
        if t == sorted(re.findall('\d+', line)):
            out.write(line)
```